# Uploading multiple files from a Google Cloud VM to Google Cloud Storage using node.js and Glob

Tags: node.js, api, npm, google-cloud-storage, glob

I am trying Node.js to upload multiple files from my Google Compute Engine VM local directory to a GCS bucket that I have already created. I am getting the following error each time I am running the script.

`TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type function`

The script:

```js
 `// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const fs = require ('fs');
const glob = require('glob');

// The name of the bucket to access, e.g. "my-bucket"
   const bucketName = "myBucket";


// Instantiates a client
const storage = new Storage({
  projectId: 'myprojectID', 
  keyFilename: 'my GCS service key'
});

//get files in the local directory of VM 

var allfiles = glob('folder/*.js', function (err, files) { 
    if (err) { 
        console.log(err); 
    }  
});


// Uploads VM local dir files  to the bucket
storage
  .bucket(bucketName)
  .upload(allfiles)
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`${allfiles} uploaded to ${bucketName}.`);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });'
```

Apparently the 'Upload' process needs the file pathnames as string. But that's what the Glob function is supposed to do. Still why is the error?

Any help will be seriously appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that you use `allfiles` as the return value for `glob`. This is not correct, the file names are available in the callback (since glob is async), not in the return value.

```
glob('folder/*.js', function (err, files) { 
    if (err) { 
        console.log(err); 
    }

    var allfiles = files;

    // Uploads VM local dir files  to the bucket
   storage
  .bucket(bucketName)
  .upload(allfiles)
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`${allfiles} uploaded to ${bucketName}.`);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });'  
});
```

Comment: Hi @mihai, many thanks for your answer. I believe it sets the context of the code right, but I am still getting the same error after implementing your suggestions...

Comment: what does `console.log(allfiles)` print ?

Comment: It's priniting the file path.

Comment: are you sure you're getting the same error and not something else?

Answer (score 0):

So I finally made the script to work. The problem was, the filepath was being captured as an object, but Google Cloud Storage service needs the path as string.

The path then had to be changed to a string using JSON.stringify and then split the resuting array to select only the file path content.

```js
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
    const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
    const fs = require('fs');
    var bucketName = 'intended GCS bucketname'; 

    const storage = new Storage({
     projectId: 'full project Id',  keyFilename: 'cloud service key'
    });

  //Invoke Glob for reading filepath in local/vm
  
     var glob = require('glob');
 
     glob('path to local/vm directory', function (err, files) {
 
    if (err) { 
        console.log(err); 
    }    
 var list = JSON.stringify(files)         ; 
      list = list.split('"')   ;    
      var listone = list[1] ;
       
storage
  .bucket(bucketName)
  .upload(listone)
  .then(() => {
       console.log(`${listone} uploaded to ${bucketName}.`);
     })
        .catch(err => {
             console.error('ERROR:', err);
           });  

 
});
```